# How can I create a drop down menu for CMS pages in Magento

Tags: cms, topmenu, submenu, drop-downs

I would like to create a simple dropdown menu for CMS pages as there are main pages and then sub pages

For example I have

ABOUT US

- sub category item

BIKE FITTING

- Road Bike fitting
- Mountain Bike fitting

SERVICING

- Kind of service 1
- Kind of service 2

etc

These are all CMS pages and I've created a sub category level in category management - I am new to Magento...so please excuse me if this is ridiculous

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>

<?php if($_menu): ?>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ol class="nav-primary">
            <?php echo $_menu ?>
        </ol>
    </nav>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This free extension can help you sort it out

[Responsive Custom Menu](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-custom-menu.html)

Comment: This seems to only add shop/product pages into the dropdown? I need the dropdowns to include CMS/Information pages?

Comment: Please follow this guide [add static page to main menu](https://web-experiment.info/articles/cat/custom_menu/post/add-static-page-main-menu/)

Comment: @phanvugiap this link is not working update new url